# Extract autodocked protein-ligand connections programatically

Tags: python, protein-structure, docking

I have 2 crystal structures, one for my protein and one for my ligand (I have several protein-ligand pairs). I am using AutoDock Vina to simulate docking, which returns another file of the ligand with updated 3D coordinates. Everything is in pdbqt format, but I can use OpenBabel to convert them if needed.

I am looking for a programmatic way (mainly python, but other languages work as well) to load both the protein and the docked ligand, then extract only the acting atoms which connect the 2 structures together (and the bonds between them).

If a direct answer is too complex, I would be happy if someone could suggest a tool/framework I could use to manipulate this sort of data easily so I can implement a solution on my own.

Comment: See a related post at Biostars for examples of how to do this with BioStructures.jl and LigPlot+: https://www.biostars.org/p/425276

Comment: Thanks. That helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pymol as a python module (`conda install -c schrodinger pymol`, not the GUI one), it is very easy.

```
import pymol2
with pymol2.PyMOL() as pymol:
     pymol.cmd.load('protein.pdbqt', 'protein') # the second is the name within pymol instance.
     pymol.cmd.load('ligand.sdf', 'ligand')
     pymol.cmd.save('neighbours.pdb','ligand expand 3') # get atoms 3 Å around
```

Done!
However, if you are doing stuff in python in the first place you might want the last line as a string: `pymol.cmd.get_pdbstr('ligand expand 3')`. Changing the selection `'ligand expand 3'` to `'byres ligand expand 3'` will save the full residues.

Alternatively you can get the atom coordinates themselves etc. with it. To see what attributes `Atom` has you have you can do this:

```
for atom in pymol.cmd.get_model('ligand expand 3').atom:
    print(dir(atom))
    break
```

Which will give a large amount of attributes, such as `atom.coord`, which is a 3-element list.