# Visualizing protein-ligand interactions with LIGPLOT or any other suitable software?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, docking

I have used DOCK software to dock 10 ligands into the protein structure.

I want to generate a pdb file that contains all 10 binding modes of the ligands together with the protein. So all together in one pdb file.

Now, what I want to know is when I give this file to LIGPLOT, is it possible to generate something like:

%polar interactions XX
%non-polar interactions XX
%hydrogen interactions XX

Is there a way to do it with LIGPLOT, if now is there some other software that can be recommended for this type of assessment?

I have been having hard time, trying to find a way or software that can perform similar type of calculation and give me similar type of output that I want.

Best

Comment: "binding modes" --> "poses".

You will need to do it programmatically. [This post for example use Python pymol](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/12862/extract-autodocked-protein-ligand-connections-programatically/12888#12888) for querying atoms. Can you use Python, Perl or Julia?

Comment: Yeah, I assumed so, cus it tends to be a bit more complicated. Unfortunately, I cant say for my self that I know any of the three languages :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualize with Discovery Studio Visualizer and Schrodinger.
Arpeggio and PLIP can generate output files of the different interactions.

Comment: Hey, thanks! already found that PLIP can do it and it works pretty well so I went for it.